# SFMLtexture shaped like player

Tags: c++, sfml

So I've been making my own shooter in C++ using SFML library. I couldn't find a proper answer to a problem I've encountered. Is there any function in SFML that would set player and enemies sprites not to the size of their textures (just rectangles), but to the "colored" areas of the source png file so the sprite would match the shape of player?

Comment: ```sf::Sprite``` can only be rectangular. You can't have a T-shaped sprite. But you can apply a partially transparent, rectangular texture to a rectangular sprite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from what I understand you probably want to create a sprite with the same bounds as your texture assuming your player is "colored" and the rest in you texture is transparent. First, your texture and the sprite (sf::Sprite) will have the same bounds as the image (png) and the scale you set, depending on the image size. However, the only thing that will be drawn onto the screen will be your "colored" part since the rest of the image has 0 as the alpha value (transparent). So there is no actual need to create a sprite which has the same "bounds" as it's visible parts. Unless, you are handling collisions.

If you are indeed handling collisions, please look into something called pixel perfect collision detection. (SFML "intersect" function uses Bounding Box detection, if you're using that.)

If this is not an answer you seek, please elaborate the question and I'll help out :)

Comment: @Hitman2104 yes, the pixel perfest collision was the thing I was looking for. I should be able to handle it from now on. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Glad to be of help. :)